# is it possible to reduce the size of slides without creating extra space in end in swiper js

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper with Product Cards</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .product-card {
      width: 150px;
      height: 239px;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .product-card img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <swiper-container class="mySwiper" pagination="true" pagination-clickable="true" slides-per-view="3"
    space-between="30" free-mode="true">
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product1.jpg" alt="Product 1">
        <h3>Product 1</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 1</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product2.jpg" alt="Product 2">
        <h3>Product 2</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 2</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product3.jpg" alt="Product 3">
        <h3>Product 3</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 3</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product4.jpg" alt="Product 4">
        <h3>Product 4</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 4</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product5.jpg" alt="Product 5">
        <h3>Product 5</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 5</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product6.jpg" alt="Product 6">
        <h3>Product 6</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 6</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product7.jpg" alt="Product 7">
        <h3>Product 7</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 7</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product8.jpg" alt="Product 8">
        <h3>Product 8</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 8</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="product-card">
        <img src="product9.jpg" alt="Product 9">
        <h3>Product 9</h3>
        <p>Description of Product 9</p>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I was working on this as it is mainly used for design 1 slides but I wanted to show product cards side by side with a minimum gap between them and have been struggling to adjust this as we can see there is a lot of space between them and can't find a way to reduce this.
I tried putting width on the swiper-slide but didn't work at the end some of my products were not showing

Comment: Your actual slides do not have any gap between them here. The have a padding-right of 30px, as you specified. But the cards you put into the slides, are simply narrower than the slides themselves. I think pretty much the only thing that would make sense here, if you do not want to limit the width of the complete slider to begin with, would be to increase the number of `slides-per-view`.

Comment: I haven't used padding on the right yet its showing in it, why is it only one slide on screen cant it be like more, and basically my concern is related to mobile viewing mobile view I want it to show other products also like 2.8 something so visually they get to know they have to swipe

Comment: The `space-between="30"` you _specified_, gets "translated" into a `padding-right: 30px` on the individual slides.

Comment: i tried reducing it still the issue is same

Comment: Yes, of course - as already explained: _"the cards you put into the slides, are simply narrower than the slides themselves."_ Removing the padding only gives the content of the slides _more_ width to extend into, but if your card don't actually do that, extend in width, then this is not going to achieve what you want. You want narrower slides to begin with, so you will have to change `slides-per-view`. For any responsiveness concerns, the library offers to configure different values for different breakpoints.